# PHP pam_auth() best administration guidelines

Tags: php, linux, security, administration, pam

Ok, so I am in the process to develop a small, temporary welcome landing page for a new site. Public visitors have the option of submitting their email address if they wish. But I also want to add a user/pass login for developers, to see the full site as it is, in its current development stage. The developers have each a user/pass on the local LAMP system.

For now, I want to identify a developer without creating two separate user systems on top of a proper website-user system, is to quickly check if that user can login with the local system. if(pam_auth($_POST["u"], $_POST["p"])) does exactly that. Simple, nice.

But then I discovered that you need to allow the apache user access to */security/pam_passwd file (or slightly better: pam_tally*). Doing that, creates a security hole.

I want to know what other developers have done to verify a user and pass with the local LAMP security system, from PHP(+apache) ? Is this the only way, or are there alternatives? Are there better suggetions?

The best answer is not necessarily code, but more a suggestion of library names or links to other solution descriptions.

Comment: This officially describes the process what I have tried out: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/pam/trunk/README?revision=291416&view=co

Comment: what's the matter with simply a standard http basic auth system and making a few usernames/passwords with that? tying a website login to the underlying server login system is a very bad idea. it provides an easy route for brute-forcing things

Comment: Of course, but then you do a port scan or something similar to learn which daemons are running, and you try a brute force on those too, nut just http. If there are routes to login with root, then why not using the website too, if its just meant to be temporarily? Also, I learn that you can use tally, which would nearly eliminate the success of a brute force attack

Comment: Most of the underlying systems can be throttled/gated by locking the account after so many attempts and what not. These could be viewed as a DoS vector now with these changes but this is no different than if someone could `ssh` into the system and attempt to login and DoS an account, so I think your approach is valid, and the comment about it being a bad idea are just being heavy handed.

Answer (score 2):

I found this implementation that someone put together using the libpam API.

***c implementation***

- original article: [PAM authentication for fun and profit](http://ditesh.gathani.org/blog/2011/06/pam-authentication-for-fun-and-profit/)

*excerpt of C implementation - pam.c*

```
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pam_response *reply;

int null_conv(int num_msg, const struct pam_message **msg, struct pam_response **resp, void *appdata_ptr) {

        *resp = reply;
        return PAM_SUCCESS;

}

static struct pam_conv conv = { null_conv, NULL };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        int retval;
        char *user, *pass;   

        if(argc == 3) {

                user = argv[1];
                pass = strdup(argv[2]);

        } else { 

                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: login [username] [password]\n");
                exit(1);

        }

        return authenticate("system-auth", user, pass);

}   

int authenticate(char *service, char *user, char *pass) {

        pam_handle_t *pamh = NULL;
        int retval = pam_start(service, user, &conv, &pamh);

        if (retval == PAM_SUCCESS) {

                reply = (struct pam_response *)malloc(sizeof(struct pam_response));
                reply[0].resp = pass;
                reply[0].resp_retcode = 0;

                retval = pam_authenticate(pamh, 0);

                if (retval == PAM_SUCCESS)
                        fprintf(stdout, "Authenticated\n");

                else
                        fprintf(stdout, "Not Authenticated\n");

                pam_end(pamh, PAM_SUCCESS);

                return ( retval == PAM_SUCCESS ? 0:1 );

        }

        return ( retval == PAM_SUCCESS ? 0:1 );
```

*command to compile it*

```
$ gcc -g -lpam -o chkpasswd pam.c
```

*example run*

```
$ ./chkpasswd myusername mypassword
```

I would imagine that with a little effort this approach could be adapted to suit your needs from within PHP.

***PHP implmentation***

As another alternative to this approach you could potentially roll your own in PHP. I found this PAM library on the PECL website that looks like what you'd want.

- http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM

I'd also take a look at how the Moodle project does it. It's discussed here.

- [Tips on configuring Moodle w/ PAM Kerberos](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=156606)

#### Using LDAP

There should be good accessibility to libraries and such to make the calls necessary to access something like LDAP over the wire to do your authentication for you. An LDAP server could also be setup on the same system as the Horde installation, configuring it for just Horde's use.

This would gain you access to the underlying system's authentication, potentially, by "wrapping" it in an LDAP service for your PHP calls to consume.

#### References

- [PAM authentication for fun and profit](http://ditesh.gathani.org/blog/2011/06/pam-authentication-for-fun-and-profit/)
- [Linux PAM guides](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/)
- [PAM tutorial (this is fairly useful)](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/AUnix2/PAM-Help.htm)
- [PAM Fedora guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Pluggable_Authentication_Modules_PAM-PAM_Configuration_Files.html)

Comment: Sadly, in 2022, the first three links are gone; the PAM Fedora guide is the sole survivor...

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn - when a get a chance later on tonight I can dig up these from archive.org. You can do the same if you have time and feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: thanks for the tip! Link #1 seems to be gone from archive.org; link #2 is now http://linux-pam.org (redirects to GitHub). I also found the [PAM tutorial (link #3) from Wayne Pollock](https://web.archive.org/web/20121031050422/http://content.hccfl.edu:80/pollock/AUnix2/PAM-Help.htm).

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn - I tried to find any remnants to that 1st link and can only find the parent page to it in wayback. I sent an email to the original author to inquire if he's simply moved the blog or if it was taken down entirely. I'll update accordingly when I get a response.